# Reminder Launch But can not open the Page in its URL

Tags: windows-phone-7

The reminder has been created with URl as below.

Problem : 
To test the reminder, I have to close the app. When this reminder is launched on Home Screen which covers with a Wallpaper , the URL in the notification reminder dialogbox which ontop of the wallpaper can not be clicked or no action when press.

would appreciate help on this problem

Thanks

```
String strReminderNameId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

string queryString = "";
queryString = "?ReminderId=" + strReminderNameId;

Uri navigationUri = new Uri("/Testing.xaml" + queryString, UriKind.Relative);

RecurrenceInterval recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.None;
recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.Daily;

Reminder reminder = new Reminder(strReminderNameId);
reminder.Title = "Testing";                
reminder.Content = "Testing 123";
reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and in my demo app it works. Could you check that Testing.xaml exists? Also have you tried to narrow it down by adding this to an empty project with only a button to add the reminder?

Comment: Thanks. Would appreciate if you can try under this condition: after created the reminder ( you need to have the page created for the url used in the reminder), close the app and turn off the screen and make sure you have a wallpaper for the homescreen. when the reminder fireup , then press anywhere on the reminder dialogbox. I have tried many times, it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behavior. When some notification coming and screen is locked - phone is wake up and show you what's happed but you couldn't click on notification to perform provided action.

Comment: If reminder shows up user should unlock screen and press it. It's simple :)

Comment: When phone is locked, the homescreen covered by wallpaper, and reminder dialogbox ONTOp of wallpaper, I dont seems to find any way to unloack the screen. To unlock, I have to press the backKey. Once it is press, the reminder dialogBox also gone without doing anything thing.

Comment: Really. Just tested and it's like a bug. I don't think about that before.